# Eclipse Maven update throwing SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, certificate, pkix

In our organization we use internal Artifactory server as maven repository. I have setup the Maven settings accordingly. Problem is when I do `Maven > Update` from Eclipse below error is thrown -

> Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from
>   https://.../artifactory/public was cached in
>   the local repository, resolution will not   be reattempted until the
>   update interval of artifactory has elapsed or updates are forced.
>   Original error: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6   from/to
>   artifactory (https://.../artifactory/public):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

This is what I have tried so far -

- Imported the Artifactory server certificate manually using `keytool` in Java `cacerts`.
- Ensured that Eclipse setting is pointing to respective Maven and JDK installations.
- Deleted m2_repo and rebuilt
- Deleted eclipse setup and setup afresh
- Restarted system

When I run Maven from command prompt it works fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Care to explain why voting down?

Comment: What version of Java are you running with, specifically the minor version, the certificates in the JVM may not be uptodate for what you're trying to talk to?

Comment: JDK 1.8.0_151; I imported manually also, anyway solved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue got resolved when I tried `Maven > Update` with `Force Update of Snapshot/Releases` enabled.

[image]